# Как перевести строку в double? Или посоветуйте другой метод ввода данных.

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
public class chisla
{
  public static void main ( String [ ] args)
  {
    BufferedReader a=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Веди`enter code here`те число а");
    BufferedReader x=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Ведите число x");
    BufferedReader e=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Ведите число E");
    String a1=a.readLine();
    String x1=a.readLine();
    String e1=a.readLine();
    double [ ] mas;
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
      mas[0]=a1;
      mas[i]=1/2*(mas[i-1]-(x1/mas[i-1]));
    }
  }
}
```

[исходная задача](http://i.piccy.info/i5/84/18/1661884/zadacha.png)

Comment: Жаль вас огорчать, но код выше - редкостная чушь :( Не понятно даже что вы пытались сделать. Непонятно, что такое a1, x1 и e1 и что за немыслимые вещи вы пытаетесь сделать в цикле с массивом, который всегда пуст.

Comment: А, теперь я понял что требовалось... ваша ссылка на задачу не была видна. Очевидно, что вы пока совсем не разобрались в теме. Вам стоит крепко подумать над этим.

Answer (score 3):

Тем не менее, несмотря на комментарий, ответ на исходный вопрос

```
import java.io.*;

public class chisla {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        try {
            System.out.println("Введите число а");
            double a = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine().trim());
            System.out.println("Введите число x");
            double x = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine().trim());
            System.out.println("Введите число E");
            double E = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine().trim());

            // дальше непонятно что делать с числами a, x и E
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Неверный формат числа");
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

если проблема перфоманса вас не интересует тогда удобрнее всего вот так:

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( System.in );
  double variable = scanner.nextDouble ();
```

p.s. старайтесь не пользоватся транслитом в ваших программах лучше все переменные, функции, классы именовать английскими именами (так принято). если же нужно чтоб их название было понятно тем кто не понимает по английски можете писать javadoc или коментарии на русском.

p.s.s. а что касается указаной вами задачи то, скорее за все, там закралась ошибка. ну не суть важно :)

```
  final double a = 5; // введенное вами число
  final double x = 3; // ввдеенное вами число
  final int n = 15; // введенное вами число
  final double e = 100; // введенное вами число

  // промежуточные данные
  final double [] array = new double [n];

  // ищем результат
  int i = 0;
  for ( ; i < n; i++ )
  {
     if ( 0 == i )
     {
        array[i] = a;
        continue;
     }

     array[i] = 0.5 * ( array[i - 1] - 1 + x / ( array[i - 1] - 1 ) );
     if ( Math.abs ( array[i] * array[i] - array[i - 1] * array[i - 1] ) < e )
     {
        break;
     }
  }

  System.out.println ( "результат:" + i );
```

Comment: В Java принято другое форматирование скобок. Выглядит очень неестественно из-за этого.

Comment: у меня дома и на роботе одно и тоже, настроеное по требованиям заказчика ^_^

Comment: Безумный заказчик :)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, в задании присутствует некорректная запись индекса i-1. Т.е. запись Yi-1 обозначает элемент, предшествующий Yi, поэтому уменьшать на 1 значение самого элемента не нужно.